# Paypal - billing cycle length?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Nothing is more confusing to me than PayPal documentation..

Basically I am trying to set a recurring payment. Each month pay 400.50 Euro for 'Membership' Of course the button they provided failed, but I found some examples and came up with:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">

        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@example.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.example.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name"  value="Membership" />
        <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- recurring=yes -->
        <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"> <!-- reattempt=yes -->
        <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> <!-- billing cycle length -->
        <input type="hidden" name="a3"  value="400.50" />
        <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

1. What value should"billing cycle length" be - now default 1?
2. Does this mean once the user clicks my button - a payment will be extracted every month or it will only work one time (that 1 value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) `p3` is the subscription duration and should be used in conjunction with the value of `t3`.

Here's the details from that page:

> p3 - Required
>
> Subscription duration. Specify an integer value in the allowable range for the units of duration that you specify with t3.
>
> t3 - Required
>
> Regular subscription units of duration.
> Allowable values are:
>
> D — for days; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 90
>
> W — for weeks; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 52
>
> M — for months; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 24
>
> Y — for years; allowable range for p3 is 1 to 5

So the current configuration is a recurring payment for only 1 Month.

I hope that this helps!

Comment: Sorry, to make sure I understand.. If i set t3 to 'Y'  and p3 =5 that specific ammount will be payed each year for 5 consecutive years, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Use "srt"  with some values greater then 1

```
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="12" /><!--- 12 Month, paypal allowedonly 12 Month i think--->
```